# App Store Rejection: Unable to reproduce crash

Tags: ios, crash, app-store

The App Store Review-Team finally took a look at my new application. 
Sadly they found a crash in a key functionality which i can't reproduce.

They are using an Retina-iPad, which i don't have, but the application has been successfully tested on a Retina-iPad, so i guess this is not the cause of the crash.

I attached the two crash reports which has been already symbolicated (Xcode says so):

```
Incident Identifier: FB200CAC-26C3-43BB-B382-5A959F19A26E
CrashReporter Key:   9b35521bd49c8385b22b5ce37201f5fb94cfb6ab
Hardware Model:      iPad3,3
Process:         VisitDenmark [3723]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/5EC8A7A0-0AD8-4C8C-A379-16836455B707/VisitDenmark.app/VisitDenmark
Identifier:      VisitDenmark
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-06-08 18:38:12.043 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.1.1 (9B206)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35281848 __kill + 8
1   VisitDenmark                    0x000ce142 0x98000 + 221506
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32dab950 __handleUncaughtException + 68
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34d5033e _objc_terminate + 122
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33f243be _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 70
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33f2444a std::terminate() + 14
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x33f2581e __cxa_rethrow + 82
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x34d502a2 objc_exception_rethrow + 6
8   CoreFoundation                  0x32d01506 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 398
9   CoreFoundation                  0x32d01366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
10  GraphicsServices                0x32e4e432 GSEventRunModal + 130
11  UIKit                           0x352e0cce UIApplicationMain + 1074
12  VisitDenmark                    0x00099f20 main (main.m:15)
13  VisitDenmark                    0x00099eb8 0x98000 + 7864

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352723a8 kevent + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x314d6f04 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 708
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x314d6c22 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 30

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35282cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32163f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32163cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  WebThread
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352820d8 __psynch_mutexwait + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3215d674 pthread_mutex_lock + 376
2   WebCore                         0x359fc4e8 _ZL17_WebTryThreadLockb + 208
3   WebCore                         0x359fc7ec _ZL14WebRunLoopLockP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 24
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32d7fb14 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32d7dd50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 252
6   CoreFoundation                  0x32d7e16a __CFRunLoopRun + 946
7   CoreFoundation                  0x32d0149e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
8   CoreFoundation                  0x32d01366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
9   WebCore                         0x35a9fc9c _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 396
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3216972e _pthread_start + 314
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x321695e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35282cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32163f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32163cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35272004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352721fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32d7f3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32d7e124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32d0149e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32d01366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x373ffbb2 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 302
7   Foundation                      0x373ffa7a -[NSThread main] + 66
8   Foundation                      0x3749358a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3216972e _pthread_start + 314
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x321695e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35282cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32163f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32163cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35272004 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x352721fa mach_msg + 50
2   CoreFoundation                  0x32d7f3ec __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 120
3   CoreFoundation                  0x32d7e124 __CFRunLoopRun + 876
4   CoreFoundation                  0x32d0149e CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 294
5   CoreFoundation                  0x32d01366 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 98
6   Foundation                      0x373f3b6e -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 250
7   Foundation                      0x3740d51c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 72
8   VisitDenmark                    0x000e31be 0x98000 + 307646
9   Foundation                      0x373ffa7a -[NSThread main] + 66
10  Foundation                      0x3749358a __NSThread__main__ + 1042
11  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3216972e _pthread_start + 314
12  libsystem_c.dylib               0x321695e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35282cd4 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32163f36 _pthread_wqthread + 610
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x32163cc8 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35282570 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x32d8363a __CFSocketManager + 726
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3216972e _pthread_start + 314
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x321695e8 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000001      r3: 0x3efc0fbc
    r4: 0x00000000    r5: 0x2fe963b1      r6: 0x2fe963b0      r7: 0x2fe96a80
    r8: 0x2fe963e0    r9: 0x00000000     r10: 0x2fe963b8     r11: 0x0000000d
    ip: 0x00000025    sp: 0x2fe9639c      lr: 0x000ce149      pc: 0x35281848
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
   0x98000 -   0x15efff +VisitDenmark armv7  <2db255fdcc333f7a922636327a0628f8> /var/mobile/Applications/5EC8A7A0-0AD8-4C8C-A379-16836455B707/VisitDenmark.app/VisitDenmark
0x2fe97000 - 0x2feb8e17  dyld armv7  <77eddfd654df393ba9c95ff01715fd08> /usr/lib/dyld
0x303bc000 - 0x303c7ff7  AccountSettings armv7  <373e59421d983c93931cfbad87b1ae35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x30515000 - 0x3055afff  GeoServices armv7  <a26be2e76e8730ab91a16502aba376be> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x3055b000 - 0x305cbffb  CoreImage armv7  <86ac6f5a267637b6b7f8a831dfc7c64b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x305cc000 - 0x305e4ff1  ChunkingLibrary armv7  <c73a4b4b38ae3702bc1feae489d31634> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x306b5000 - 0x306b6ffd  CoreSurface armv7  <97f871f09f503c98a6371c2b657430d8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x306c3000 - 0x30720fff  StoreServices armv7  <6ce256d3cf433e4aa1af8d696bf1f75d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x30721000 - 0x30721fff  Accelerate armv7  <55b24cf91a8b3532bde6733c96f14c08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x30734000 - 0x30745ff4  libxpc.dylib armv7  <ccf25b1e49ce3b2fa58d8c8546755505> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3075e000 - 0x307ddffd  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <bf01f5ed47b033d8bde30d735ff44416> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x307de000 - 0x30815fff  Security armv7  <eea56f71fde83c2981f9281dc7823725> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x30970000 - 0x309acff7  AppSupport armv7  <311eac85b2a433a884dacba77217b49e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x309b6000 - 0x309bcfff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <aa2bcba6fc7a36a191958fef2e995475> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x309bd000 - 0x309bdffe  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <ebd2dddf55d83cf48a18913968775960> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x309cb000 - 0x30b71eef  CoreData armv7  <b0215b6d4d143859a2b313ecade095ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x30cdd000 - 0x30cecffc  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <70ac33720f513f0f97ea2279260678ca> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x30ced000 - 0x30d01ffb  PersistentConnection armv7  <54091a638f8731cd85ccf00fa06972c3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x30d2a000 - 0x30d9eff7  MediaControlSender armv7  <87315c54b2293ab589950341ff91b45d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x30d9f000 - 0x30da3fff  CertUI armv7  <f503892ef60e36108d28d8f9d6144d2a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x30ebe000 - 0x30efaff7  iCalendar armv7  <f2836083051132d3aa40ad82d7f73aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x30efb000 - 0x30f30ffe  DataAccess armv7  <89fd0c22338b37538cf61803a0bca9e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x30f31000 - 0x30f32fff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <6a8f2f33c7543808a0f4599101c3b61a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x31156000 - 0x311aeffb  CoreAudio armv7  <be335e8eb6f93594b028a6ddd503a183> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x311af000 - 0x311beff2  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d84c3fd0e7bd36e78c256f2f4c5a4e91> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x31428000 - 0x31440fff  Notes armv7  <724966ed5cd4395cb70f9c996b123f53> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x31441000 - 0x31443ffe  MobileInstallation armv7  <215d93dbb0f63cbf828f9126eb7b5349> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x314d3000 - 0x314e9fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <9ecfaef4110a3bf9a92d12f0fe8d1d78> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3151e000 - 0x31522ffd  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <9a17d07b5a3b38cfafdf16f78c99b572> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x31523000 - 0x31548ff9  OpenCL armv7  <f4b08361179a3f6bb033415b0d7c6251> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x31579000 - 0x3157afff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <9fdc27af7350323bbc7d98e14e027907> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x315b6000 - 0x31678ffb  Celestial armv7  <19617260ee073e23b95e456d93930aea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x316ec000 - 0x31709ff7  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <50863bcbf478323e96a8e5b1a83ea6f9> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x3170a000 - 0x3171bfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <e6144ba265da3bb7b9a263aa1a29b054> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x31bc5000 - 0x31bc5fff  vecLib armv7  <a2cfe25e77aa36bfb4a30b2d0d2dd465> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31d44000 - 0x31dfafff  AVFoundation armv7  <35cb7a0eb1dc3554a777c1cc11cb0415> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x31f49000 - 0x31f4bffd  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <d4d4aa3090c83e87bcb15ed00b93fd5c> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x31f4e000 - 0x31f4efff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <e0a73a57795f3e1698a52ebe6fc07005> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x31f4f000 - 0x31f52ffe  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <f5cc4b97ce9432da9426f12621453325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x31f6a000 - 0x31f81fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <696bb0630b19388da0d72e685bcf6e28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x31ff0000 - 0x31ff7fff  MailServices armv7  <ab2388ce733e38b7a261273a401bbbf1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x31ff8000 - 0x31ffdff7  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <52e874396c393ed29099789ce702cfe2> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x3210d000 - 0x32157ff9  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <f1fbb825def23043830a095b953a9c94> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x3215b000 - 0x321e7ff3  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <f859ce1ad1773f0ba98d7c6e135b7697> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x321eb000 - 0x321ecfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <9aede8d6579d3430ac39ae5f95cce498> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x321f4000 - 0x322e5ff3  QuartzCore armv7  <35d64a9da5523ae08c9e41511fd3061b> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x3250a000 - 0x325b7ff7  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <58d47f064e0232119f4b838ad659f9c1> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x325b8000 - 0x325b9fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <402f8956975d3b6fb86ab9b31a43242c> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x325f1000 - 0x325f1ffd  liblangid.dylib armv7  <644ff4bcfbf337b5b5859e3f0fc0a9a8> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x32887000 - 0x328d1ff3  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <441b42aca07b3da39feab25f8349918f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x32930000 - 0x32934fff  Marco armv7  <8dea3e558fe534ff868fc92e215ce53b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x32938000 - 0x329beffc  CoreMotion armv7  <6a9355d5a8e238b5b8f193605d509e15> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x329bf000 - 0x32aadffa  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <2cfefe2ad1d335dd9549562910e7a2e2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x32ab6000 - 0x32b04fff  CoreLocation armv7  <44550ebedf23334d85441d9743b74e03> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x32b57000 - 0x32b60fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <4a15e845dc6f3a4a980de66c1cc44c42> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x32c40000 - 0x32c6cfff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <3aacc5b650e037c086a8ff6657d154bf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x32cf2000 - 0x32e09ff9  CoreFoundation armv7  <6d450fe923d7387f8b01845e0edd713d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x32e32000 - 0x32e36ffe  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <42dbc26828e934acabb4f3b0a35d8250> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32e4a000 - 0x32e54fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <cb64e146a8ee3fda9e80ffae1ccc9c5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x32e58000 - 0x33119fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <0e94e9a7e7a334649afaccae0f1215a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x335c3000 - 0x3360cff7  AddressBook armv7  <b17a2962e9043e0385c3c2c652155f2b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x336db000 - 0x336e3ffe  MobileWiFi armv7  <b76c3e9fb78234c392058250d4620e72> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x336ee000 - 0x33704ff3  libmis.dylib armv7  <258bc92be5823b239b4412dd42cb4807> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x33705000 - 0x33724fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <0c55744b6f7335eebba4ca2c3d10b43c> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x33725000 - 0x3372affe  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <27bb5462450732e380f5a2c170546e93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x3372b000 - 0x33767fff  IMFoundation armv7  <253125b9103c3d13b66923ac6893c25b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x33822000 - 0x33827ffe  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <dc11c5c2cbe73a6288a6094ebf5de673> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x33828000 - 0x3382eff3  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <9e45ce468a6f31e5b8263f2c224aa800> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x33830000 - 0x33894fff  MessageUI armv7  <da7af4f9494b35558bf7892dfdb36ee3> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x33922000 - 0x33b4fff7  MediaToolbox armv7  <c3098478486032c6aff336fa711c4fc6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x33b71000 - 0x33c1bfff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <bf822cc1a3243ae7b104cf73ca22d352> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x33c3e000 - 0x33d83ffb  CoreGraphics armv7  <903545b89a7f311d95100ac7d1d44709> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x33d86000 - 0x33de9ffb  IMCore armv7  <046b6b615a743057b59d4aaba8a91d61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x33f20000 - 0x33f27ff7  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <bab4dcbfc5943d3fbb637342d35e8045> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x33f42000 - 0x33f45ffc  CoreTime armv7  <a398de5ba1e43a11b7008e9bb5a7f6fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x33f46000 - 0x33f53ff7  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <750a0de73a733019a77144b805d4d2f8> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x33f90000 - 0x33fe1ff6  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <c352af5a742e3c7a8d4d7e5f6f454793> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x3409b000 - 0x340c4fff  AppleAccount armv7  <2ba44023410231fcb3f72f762ea3ce6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x340c5000 - 0x340efffe  Ubiquity armv7  <b6c22aaf6eaf3876b7ed3cf114c08539> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Ubiquity.framework/Ubiquity
0x340f0000 - 0x340f0fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <a80aaa9989483ce3a496a061fd1e9e0a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x340f6000 - 0x3419cfff  AddressBookUI armv7  <da424fecc66e3628ab03378ae80b38fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x3419d000 - 0x341bdfff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <39348471007e39dab80af68b08390456> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x341c1000 - 0x34299ff6  vImage armv7  <caf3648be2933384b6aa1ae7408ab4f0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x3429c000 - 0x342a4fff  Librarian armv7  <aa068e49712d3af3884190a0e0cd557d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Librarian.framework/Librarian
0x342a7000 - 0x342adfff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <9406297de3e43742887890662a87ab53> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x342c0000 - 0x342c8fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <0e846afacf823d2b8c029cc3010a8253> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x346d7000 - 0x34c1bff5  FaceCoreLight armv7  <f326d88709683520b251dc53cb847c11> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x34c1c000 - 0x34c32ff7  DictionaryServices armv7  <6ed2e967136f37d4a4b9b318d6c43b83> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x34d47000 - 0x34e0dd63  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <90014d1bc583366d85622e43097df416> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x34e39000 - 0x34e3ffff  MobileIcons armv7  <ed1b46f917903c9b9baaa2be4392dafe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x34e40000 - 0x34e4aff7  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <40e4045fb79e382b8833707746cf28b1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x34e4c000 - 0x34e4cfff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <eb82984fa36c329387aa518aa5205f3d> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x34e51000 - 0x34e99ffe  CoreMedia armv7  <e274e1b894753b2eb05cf7b22a36d0c1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x34e9a000 - 0x34ea1fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <38132ecfd74b325fb1a4142bab663c19> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x34ea2000 - 0x34ea5ffd  NetworkStatistics armv7  <7848d8ebad99367cb4f7f4e3fe88e5d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
0x34f76000 - 0x34fc7fff  CoreText armv7  <5bfac4ee88d03d5b87a1f105abb7756c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x350ad000 - 0x350c6ff7  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <1828cddc5dd93c61afbefb59587d7f8a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x350c7000 - 0x35105fff  IOKit armv7  <fcda71d29d6136dfbd84c1725f4998e5> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x35106000 - 0x3510affd  IOSurface armv7  <443ac3aab9283da480dd9dcda3c5c88e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x35271000 - 0x35287ffd  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <311f379a9fde305d80c1b22b7dd2e52a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x35288000 - 0x3529eff5  EAP8021X armv7  <952fcfdec0633aff923768fca1a26fcb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x3529f000 - 0x352a9ffb  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <e8248c797b9b363594bb652ddf7ce16d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x352af000 - 0x35751ff3  UIKit armv7  <cd513a2f22f53d698c3e10f6fe48a63e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x358b3000 - 0x358f6fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <95b49daf4cf038b6bea8010bba3a1e26> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x35926000 - 0x35935fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <a2363f8ed49932dba415d2d4cd32fb74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x35936000 - 0x3593afff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <998fccc16cf735dbb62324202995e193> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x359f6000 - 0x361b5ffb  WebCore armv7  <2690c38c9c5f3c09975d619dd1dfbed7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x361b6000 - 0x36286ffc  WebKit armv7  <3c5dd2ec46fe3e189c25bba78ad88fa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x36287000 - 0x362d3fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <b8f80d5d594c31d2b5d8fba9fdedb7e1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x362e3000 - 0x36327ffb  MobileCoreServices armv7  <757226927a873d5492be721908077b48> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x3632b000 - 0x3632efff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <356cb66612e836968ef24e6e5c3364cc> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3632f000 - 0x36378ff0  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <5b690e5dd5a43a7fb166ade9fe58a7a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x3638a000 - 0x363c2ff3  VideoToolbox armv7  <9f25f38d1cd13a1daff99cfde8884410> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x363c3000 - 0x364e8ff3  JavaScriptCore armv7  <2ffc6c87b94434288366bd53765ee267> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x36a6e000 - 0x36b45ff1  CFNetwork armv7  <765a472c824830eea91b8f02d12867e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x36b46000 - 0x36b47fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <977b0ad6f2f433108b4a0324a57cd2ab> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x36bc4000 - 0x36c3dfff  ProofReader armv7  <6db611d8df6530d480f97a40bc519f70> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x36c75000 - 0x36cb4ff3  QuickLook armv7  <802b1092542a3017a0380632502610d4> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x36cb5000 - 0x36e72ff7  ImageIO armv7  <02e3578171fa3b6a969b244275fd2bab> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x36e73000 - 0x36e96ff7  Bom armv7  <c3435ecd2e5839f89de51edad0e1bb00> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x36e97000 - 0x36eccff7  SystemConfiguration armv7  <4464a4e3bb3f32f7abaa35ebf31fda49> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x370bd000 - 0x372a1ff7  AudioToolbox armv7  <c91e27850452330ea804db6408840fd2> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x37337000 - 0x3736bfff  MIME armv7  <d30292ea8f7e360fa5f5d5b1b62b602d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x373d4000 - 0x373e0fff  CoreVideo armv7  <364fa32d513f3c11b50970120545f1a8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x373ef000 - 0x3756dfff  Foundation armv7  <c40ddb073142315bb4ebb214343d0b7f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x375dd000 - 0x3761afff  FTServices armv7  <3f23418319a03a589dd5cac7df20e238> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x37741000 - 0x37744fff  ActorKit armv7  <434c756a6b053f4ba3c954cfccddbf59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x37757000 - 0x377f0fff  EventKit armv7  <d67aa1508ee7306b8e2a45c76ffddff0> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x3781d000 - 0x37820ff8  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <b2c05d8601c13be884097192dca4e187> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x378af000 - 0x378b3ffc  AggregateDictionary armv7  <3a3a33f3a05538988c6e2bb363dc46a8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x37949000 - 0x3794affe  DataMigration armv7  <d77f0e8f39ee37f5a2ac713a3fd9e693> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3794b000 - 0x3798bffd  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <40448706190031f6b0d9636cc11ee81d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x37a91000 - 0x37a97ffe  MobileKeyBag armv7  <e1f06241ef0e3f0aae00f15df572077e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x37af2000 - 0x37af5ffd  libmacho.dylib armv7  <e52b77623bd031bc807e77029566c777> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x37af6000 - 0x37b02ff0  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <bdb2b4d1a78c39c1ba60d791207aed2a> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x37b03000 - 0x37b3eff7  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <55941c96cf1f3b048e72a148c4496c16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x37b65000 - 0x37b69ffc  libcache.dylib armv7  <d6a7436ed8dc33d795c9b42baf864882> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x37c20000 - 0x37c50ffe  ContentIndex armv7  <7a64670bb2ff3ee39ddee1dc1c72f92d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x37c51000 - 0x37c66fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <66f7557fa4b43979b186e00271839fdb> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x37c67000 - 0x37c6bfff  FTClientServices armv7  <21de970d7ebb3e7fb502a0a5451b0806> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x37c6c000 - 0x37db5ff1  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <b70646b63f1f3b33896dd8cb91b8dab1> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x37db6000 - 0x37dd9ffd  MobileSync armv7  <e42604c550283f4aa517ae8f108b340f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x37df7000 - 0x37e1bff7  PrintKit armv7  <08509c7bc915358b953de6f5cbef5c56> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x37e1c000 - 0x37e21ffe  ApplePushService armv7  <f424c0340de637c08bbeb4f3bd8c6eaf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x37e8c000 - 0x37e98fff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <36ce86a3dc8c344596c8c325615f374b> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x37e99000 - 0x37ea8ff7  OpenGLES armv7  <e80acc691001301e96101bb89d940033> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x37f3e000 - 0x37fecffb  Message armv7  <573d0118246d3d9d8aed17e7ee2faec7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
```

Comment: Questions usually have a `?` in them somewhere...

Comment: They're testing it on an iPad 3 running iOS 5.1.1. Are you sure you're not trying to call selectors present only in the newer iOS versions?